# In nested function second function is not working

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, nested-function

I created a useState hook to store the ID fetching from the first function., and the initial value of the hook is an empty string(''). But the problem is when I save the file two times the hook stores the ID that I have fetched otherwise it is completely empty.

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState(' ');

  const getCMSID = () => {
    let url = `${URL}/store-api/category`;
    let getId = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
      },
    };
    fetch(url, getId)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setId(json.elements[0].cmsPageId))
      .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));

    const getCMSPage = () => {
      const cmsUrl = `${URL}/store-api/cms/${id}`;
      let getcms = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
        },
      };
      fetch(cmsUrl, getcms)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          setData(json.sections);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('Error:' + err));
    };
    getCMSPage();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getCMSID();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I got the solution and it works.

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getCMSID = () => {
    let url = `${URL}/store-api/category`;
    let getId = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
      },
    };
    fetch(url, getId)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        getCMSPage(json.elements[0].cmsPageId);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));

    const getCMSPage = gId => {
      const cmsUrl = `${URL}/store-api/cms/${gId}`;
      let getcms = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
        },
      };
      fetch(cmsUrl, getcms)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          setData(json.sections);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('Error:' + err));
    };
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getCMSID();
  }, []);
```

@credit **Nayeem M. Muzahid**

Answer (score 0):

***useState*** hook is asynchronous. So do not set something using ***useState*** and use it inside the same function. As per your code, you can just use the ID directly without using the set value.

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [id, setId] = useState(' ');

const getCMSID = () => {
let url = `${URL}/store-api/category`;
let getId = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
  },
};
fetch(url, getId)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => { return setId(json.elements[0].cmsPageId)})
  .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));

 const getCMSPage = () => {
  const cmsUrl = `${URL}/store-api/cms/${globalID}`;
  let getcms = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
    },
  };
  fetch(cmsUrl, getcms)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      setData(json.sections);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('Error:' + err));
};
 getCMSPage();
};
 useEffect(() => {
  getCMSID();
 }, []);
```

And use the value of the hook outside the function if you need it.

Comment: I can't use an id like this because the id is also fetching from the first function and storing that id into a useState hook to use in the nested function.

Comment: then store the id in the global variable and use the global variable on the inner function.

Comment: how I store that value in a global variable.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check this out. Let me know if its works. If it does not, I will try different method.

Comment: not working, the globalID variable that you have created remains an empty string in the second function.

Comment: can you provide sandbox link of the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245785/discussion-between-nayeem-m-muzahid-and-dipesh-kumar-sah).

Comment: can you check without API KEY and URL because I am working on the project of shopware.

Comment: ok. let's see If can fix it.

Comment: check the room chat

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-water-oubpjl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark